# How do I change the Matplotlib axis limits for a plot given by a specific library(trackpy)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, trackpy

[This function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Oxs.png) gives me a plot. However I want to change the default axis. It says in documentation that ax refers to:

ax : matplotlib axes object, optional.

I tried to input the axis limit as ax=([0 100 0 500]) for example but it recognizes it as a tuple or a list. How is the correct way to input it?

Thanks!

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim

Answer (score 1):

The [`trackpy.plot_traj`](http://soft-matter.github.io/trackpy/v0.3.0/generated/trackpy.plot_traj.html) functions returns a matplotlib axes object.

So, you'll want something like:

```py
ax = trackpy.plot_traj(traj)
ax.set_xlim([0, 100])
ax.set_ylim([0, 500])
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Unfortunately this doesn't work. I still get the same result. https://imgur.com/a/1c1WoB5

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm unable to replicate this problem. I downloaded an example [dataset here](https://github.com/soft-matter/trackpy-examples/tree/master/sample_data/bulk_water) and followed the instructions [here](http://soft-matter.github.io/trackpy/v0.3.0/tutorial/walkthrough.html) to create a trajectory plot. With this I was able to successfully alter the x and y limits with the above command.

Comment: What version of ```trackpy``` are you using? You can find this out as ```tp.__version__```